# How to split the given format into date and time in android

Tags: java, android

Given Format:
`2017-03-08 13:27:00`

I want to spilt it into 2 strings 
1 for date and 1 for time 
for

E.g.
`08-03-2017`
`13:27:00`

Comment: Well, I would parse the whole thing using SimpleDateFormat, then format again using two different SimpleDateFormat instances, one for the time and one for the date. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `str.split("\\s");` zeroth index would be date, first would be time. Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Can you plz give me format of SimpleDateFormat instances

Comment: I have already tried  SimpleDateFormat formatter1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First if your date in String format then Parse it to Date and then try it.

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Date today = new Date();
            DateFormat timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance();
            DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance();
            timeFormat.format(today);
            dateFormat.format(today);
            System.out.println("Time: " + timeFormat.format(today));
            System.out.println("Date: " + dateFormat.format(today));
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Time: 1:25:31 AM
Date: 31 Mar, 2017
```

Hope this help !

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class FormateDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date_s = "2017-03-08 13:27:00";

        // *** note that it's "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" not "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"  
        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = dt.parse(date_s);

        // *** same for the format String below
        SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println("Date :"+dt1.format(date));

          dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            System.out.println("Time :"+dt1.format(date));
    }

}
```

It gives output like this

> > Date :2017-03-08  Time :13:27:00

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
String datetime= "2017-03-08 13:27:00";
String[] divide= datetime.split("\\s");
String date = divide[0]; //2017-03-08
String time= divide[1]; // 13:27:00
```